# I am using flutter version 3.3.5. and I am getting this error message "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps." for the code below

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, asynchronous, mobile

```js
httpErrorHandle(
        response: res,
        context: context,
        onSuccess: () async {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).setUser(res.body);
          await prefs.setString('x-auth-token', jsonDecode(res.body)['token']); 

       
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            HomeScreen.routeName,
            (route) => false,
          );

        },
      );
```

I didn't find any solution related, this code is crashing the application

Answer (score 2):

```
httpErrorHandle(
        response: res,
        context: context,
        onSuccess: () async {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).setUser(res.body);
          await prefs.setString('x-auth-token', jsonDecode(res.body)['token']); 

            //if you are using a statefulWidget do:
            if(!mounted) return;

           //if it is a statelessWidget do:
           if(!context.mounted) return;
       
            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            HomeScreen.routeName,
            (route) => false,
          );

        },
      );
```

Comment: Hi Etornam i am getting these error messages "Undefined name 'mounted'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name." "The getter 'mounted' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.
Try importing the library that defines 'mounted', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'mounted'.dartundefined_getter"

Comment: Are you using a StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget?

Comment: No, it is a normal class. If you want I can share the complete code by email.